# What is a trampolined interpreter?

Tags: programming-languages, interpreters

Can anyone explain me what is a trampolined interpreter? I am versed with relevant concepts viz. procedural languages, continuations etc but am finding difficulty understanding the definition/need for trampolining. Please help.

Comment: What research have you done?  We expect you to do serious research on your own before asking.  Where did you come across the phrase?  What is the context?

Comment: no offence but issueing the canonical google search supplies a textbook reference for trampolining (downloadable for the brave ...) - have you run across a non-standard use of the term ?

Comment: I am studying Essentials of Programming Languages by Friedman and Wand, I discovered it only there, but cannot understand. (Chapter 5)

Comment: @user2239690 Then please extend your question by adding the title of the book and the chapter/section. Also, adding the specific example that you don't understand would be useful.

Comment: @user2239690 in a nutshell: it's about delayed execution of tail recursion. a recursive call C as the last operation in a function usually incurs generating a new activation record (stack frame). however, the current frame at the time of the call will not be used anymore. so instead of opening another layer of recursion, defer C and return first. however, you need the proper arguments to C which might depend on local vars, so you have to wrap up the call + actual params as a return value. pro: less stack space, less function call overhead. does the explanation make sense?

Comment: @collapsar yes it does very much. let me get back to you if I have further doubts. Thanks.